# Create a column based on "adjusted group_by" - R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataframe with names of coaches of football clubs.
Sometimes, after a while, the same coach returns to the team after being fired in the past.
If I use a group_by, the output df would aggregate both coaches as a same group.
However, I want that this create different groups. I do not know if I made myself clear, but I think this example would provide a better explanation than my text :D

If there is a package or other function that would do that, no problem!

Thanks in advance!

Example

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
  name = c("Jose","Jose", "Maria","Maria","Jose","Jose","Jose")
)
#Desired Output
adjusted_df <- tibble(
  name = c("Jose","Jose", "Maria","Maria","Jose","Jose","Jose"),
  number = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
)
# I think after this desired output, I could group by name and number
```

Comment: Would something like `df$number <- cumsum(df$name != lag(df$name) & duplicated(df$name)) + 1` be close to what you're looking for? Or would you consider just assigning a change in `name` with a unique id, such as `df$number <- rleid(df$name)` using `data.table`? In the latter case, you can also `group_by` with both `name` and `number`...

Comment: Many thanks!
Both solutions would help!
The second one, with data.table, it is pretty simple and useful.
In the first one the only limitation is that I would want that return it to number one if a new name is included it after Jose, for example "Pedro". But I really appreciate it, because the second it will solve the problem and it is simple!
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you unique ids if you group by name and id. It isn't the exact sequence you specified but this would work.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
  name = c("Jose","Jose", "Maria","Maria","Jose","Jose","Jose")) |> 
  mutate(id = cumsum(ifelse(name != lag(name) | is.na(lag(name)), 1, 0)))
```

Comment: Many thanks!!
I really appreciate it!!
This is what I need it!